# No Display with Navi10 Gpu

Tags: amd-graphics

I have a Sapphire Radeon 5600XT which came out around a month or so ago. I am able to boot the live CD (18.04) sometimes and install ubuntu but after I reboot and start the freshly installed OS I see HDD activity but the screen either goes black or sticks at the loading ubuntu screen with the dots. When I press ctl-alt-del it does the shutdown process (I can see HDD activity) and then reboots.

After messing around I was able to figure out that using `nomodeset` in place of `quiet splash` in the grub kernel arguments can get me into the installed OS, but of course the resolution is locked at 1024x768 and I guess the GPU specific kernel modules are not being loaded.

A couple of times I was able to get to the lower run level screens that shows text output of what is going on and I can see messages like:

```
[drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring gfx timeout
```

I've stumbled across some people running into this but not figured out a work around yet. I've also downloaded the amd linux drivers and installed them but it's not helped and also it shows some warnings at the end of the install (I think because I'm booted in with `nomodeset`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after some more trial and error and googling, I stumbled upon this reddit post: https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/f52fnl/hardware_update_on_the_rx_5600_xts_performance_on/

Which mentions exactly the problem I was having albeit on another ubuntu-based OS. The OP mentions that he got it to work but had to do a few things:

1. install the latest firmware
2. install the latest mesa packages
3. install the latest kernel

So I gave that a whack and it actually worked. Specifically do the following:

1. Boot the 18.04 live cd, press `e` while `try ubuntu without installing` is selected. Replace the text `quiet splash` with `nomodeset` and press `F10` to boot. You should be greeted by the desktop in all its 720P glory... Install ubuntu from there as normal
2. Upon restart, when you get the grub menu, do the same thing again. With `ubuntu` highlighted, press `e` and replace `quiet splash` with `nomodeset` and press `F10` to continue booting. Sometimes the grub menu is all purple with no boot options, press `esc` if this happens and then do the `nomodeset` trick as described.
3. Once in you can use the following script to get the OS patched to boot properly with this card:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
set -e

#grab the latest navi10 firmware
sudo apt install git
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
cd linux-firmware
git checkout $(git describe --tags)
sudo cp -rp amdgpu/* /lib/firmware/amdgpu/
#sudo update-initramfs -u #this happens when we install the new kernel below
cd -

#grab newest mesa drivers and update other packages...
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade #too lazy to list individual packages

#grab a newer kernel
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.5.6/linux-headers-5.5.6-050506_5.5.6-050506.202002240832_all.deb
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.5.6/linux-headers-5.5.6-050506-generic_5.5.6-050506.202002240832_amd64.deb
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.5.6/linux-image-unsigned-5.5.6-050506-generic_5.5.6-050506.202002240832_amd64.deb
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.5.6/linux-modules-5.5.6-050506-generic_5.5.6-050506.202002240832_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

That's it, reboot and let the OS start itself as normal. Your resolution should match whatever your display supports and your GPU should now be used properly. At the time of writing there are still some strange things going on. If you put the computer to sleep and wake it there is massive flickering even if you restart `gdm`, so I suppose we'll need to wait a bit for better drivers.